# Flutter InfiniteScroll with Listview.builder refresh the data instead of adding it to the list

Tags: laravel, flutter, listview, infinite-scroll, flutter-futurebuilder

i am very new in flutter...

So, i tried to follow tutorial that sometimes i change it litle bit so it could run like i want it to. so, i am making an infinitescroll to get the data from API which has pagination in it (laravel pagination).

Here is the code that i am working on

```
class searchBerita extends StatefulWidget {
  const searchBerita({super.key});

  @override
  State<searchBerita> createState() => _searchBeritaState();
}

class _searchBeritaState extends State<searchBerita> {
  int page = 1;
  List<ArticleList>? articleList;
  ScrollController _listController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listController.addListener(() {
      print('scroll: ' + _listController.position.maxScrollExtent.toString());
      if (_listController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
          _listController.position.pixels) {
        page++;
        print('page : ' + page.toString());
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List<ArticleList>> getListArtikel() async {
    List<ArticleList> articleData = [];
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl + '/guest/search-article?page=${page}'),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

        for (Map<String, dynamic> item in data['data']['data_article']) {
          articleData.add(ArticleList.fromJson(item));
        }

        return articleList = articleData;
      } else {
        print('failed');
        throw Exception('failed');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw Exception('failed');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: [
          const _TemukanBerita(),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getListArtikel(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ArticleList>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
                  }

                  return Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: _listController,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length ?? 0,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            try {
                              Provider.of<Article>(context, listen: false)
                                  .getDetailArtikel(
                                      context, snapshot.data![index].slug!);
                            } catch (err) {
                              print(err);
                            }
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                            child: Material(
                              child: Material(
                                child: Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.grey[300]!, width: 1.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(10))),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      CachedNetworkImage(
                                        imageUrl: snapshot.data![index]!.image!,
                                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                                          return Container(
                                            height: 100,
                                            width: 100,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(8.0)),
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                  image: imageProvider,
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url,
                                                downloadProgress) =>
                                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                value:
                                                    downloadProgress.progress),
                                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                            Icon(Icons.error),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width -
                                                200,
                                            child: Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Row(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Container(
                                                          width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                      context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width *
                                                              0.5,
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            snapshot
                                                                .data![index]
                                                                .title!,
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    "Sofia",
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .black),
                                                            overflow:
                                                                TextOverflow
                                                                    .clip,
                                                            maxLines: 2,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                const SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Icon(
                                                      Icons.schedule,
                                                      size: 18,
                                                    ),
                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                      width: 5,
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${DateTime.now().difference(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data![index].tanggal_publish!)).inHours} hours ago',
                                                    ),
                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                      width: 20,
                                                    ),
                                                    const Icon(
                                                      Icons.visibility,
                                                      size: 18,
                                                    ),
                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                      width: 5,
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${snapshot.data![index].jumlahView!} views',
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 12),
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am sorry, it is very long, i am still working on how to make it simple. i think the infinite scroll is working. but there are some issues here i dont know how to resolve.

**1. the scroll is very weird, it looks like that the scroll working only on the listview.builder not the whole page. it made the the state triggered even before i reach the bottom of the list**.

**2. the data seems not added to the early list but it looks like its overwrite the list. so the list is changing but i lost the earlier list. i want it to still add the earlier list as well**

i've been tring to look for a lot of solution but it seems like i dont fully understand whats wrong.

This is the article model that might responsible for this frustating problem:

```
class ArticleList {
  ArticleList({
    this.id,
    this.slug,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.category,
    this.jumlahView,
    this.tanggal_publish,
    this.author,
  });

  final int? id;
  final String? slug;
  final String? image;
  final String? title;
  final String? category;
  final int? jumlahView;
  final String? tanggal_publish;
  final String? author;

  factory ArticleList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArticleList(
      id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
      slug: json["slug"] == null ? null : json["slug"],
      title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
      image: json["image"] == null ? null : json["image"],
      category: json["category"] == null ? null : json["category"],
      jumlahView: json["jumlahView"] == null ? null : json["jumlahView"],
      author: json["author"] == null ? null : json["author"],
      tanggal_publish:
          json["tanggal_publish"] == null ? null : json['tanggal_publish']);

  static List<ArticleList> fromJsonList(dynamic jsonList) {
    final articles = <ArticleList>[];
    if (jsonList == null) return articles;

    if (jsonList is List<dynamic>) {
      for (final json in jsonList) {
        articles.add(
          ArticleList.fromJson(json),
        );
      }
    }

    return articles;
  }
}
```

i dont know what is wrong, it seems like i am following the tutorial very carefully. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple issue here,

See you have two lists os type `List<ArticleList>`, one is a class variable with name `articleList` and another is in the function `getListArtikel()` with name `articleData`. Now you are fetching list of article from the api with pagination and it will be saved in the list `articleData` so it will have list for that page only and after you're returning like `return articleList = articleData` which means you're replacing the new data with old one.

You can do two things you can have only one list `articleList` you just fetch new data and add them in this list below:

```
for (Map<String, dynamic> item in data['data']['data_article']) {
   articleList.add(ArticleList.fromJson(item));
}
```

Or you can have both the list just at the return statement you can add the new data which is now in `articleData` and at to the `articleList` like below:

```
return articleList.addAll(articleData);
```

so the `articleList` will have the all the data and `articleData` will have data for that page only.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. i thought about it earlier and i tried that solution but i got "Null check operator used on a null value"....

Comment: And when i change the initialization into late artlicleList so that i dont have to put null safety operator i got "Field 'articleList' has not been initialized." error.... its like im going in a circle of error

Comment: That is cause your are using null assertion on the null value at so many places. tell me why is your `articleList` is nullable where it not have any purpose. And you're returning the container having the listView.builder without any check if the `snapshot.hasdata` or something; you can return it from the else of  `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done`

Comment: just like i mention on the question. i just following the tutorial and solve some null safety problem cause it seems like it cant run without it. but i think i just dont fully understand why and how the null safety works. i already found the solution on my own. But thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i have an update for my problem, because i cant really remove the null check operator and also put late in articleList variable and i dont understand why it couldnt read the initialization on my futureBuilder. so i change how i initialize articleList on the state class into this:

```
  List<ArticleList> articleList = <ArticleList>[];
```

and it just work like magic. just added `<ArticleList>[]`, the problem i've been trying to solve for two days is gone.

i dont know whats the explanation to this, cause i am still new here. i apreciate your help though... thank you...